Lower bound for the large deviation and concentration probability
Recently, I learned about large deviation results and concentration inequalities, such as the following upper bound:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Prob}[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| > \epsilon] < e^{-N I(\epsilon)},
\end{equation}
where $I(\epsilon)$ is some rate function. These provide upper bounds on probabilities of deviations.  Also I learned some concentration inequality like sub-Gaussian
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Prob}[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| > \epsilon] < e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2}{\sigma^2}},
\end{equation}
In contrast, it seems that there are relatively few known lower bounds in this context. I am aware of the Paley–Zygmund inequality, but I am particularly interested in lower bounds with an exponential form, similar to sub-Gaussian upper bounds.
Are there any well-known results or frameworks addressing such lower bounds in the context of concentration inequalities? I would appreciate any recommendations for introductory material or textbooks that cover this topic.

This may be a good starting point: http://jamesyli.com/wenbo_li/papers/01-survey-LiShao.pdf

There is a book, written by the recent Abel price winner Michel Talagrand, that is entirely devoted to these type of questions, at least for the independent case. The book is called upper and lower bounds for stochastic processes. It does require some prior knowledge, but it leaves out many difficulties regarding measurability. There is also a first edidion of the book.
